# Detect how many rows are in chinese in a dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement, dataframe

I've got 10,000 rows of data, i want to see how many of those rows contain chinese in the 'txt' column of the dataframe

I've tried using langdetect but i get the error stating that it only works on strings.

Current method is:

```
counter = 0


with open("annotation_sample.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if "汉" in row[1]:
            counter = counter ++ 1


print (counter)
```

which works but only if it contains '汉' which is merely 1 character out of all the possible chinese characters therefore doesnt return correct results.

where am i going wrong, am i tackling this the wrong way? quite new to pandas and python in general so any help would be great!

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

df = pd.read_csv("annotation_sample.csv")
df = df.drop(['id', 'profile_id', 'created', 'document_id'], axis=1)

df

df.apply(lambda x: detect(x))
```

[image: the dataframe]

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each row of your `txt` column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect
import re

df = pd.read_csv("annotation_sample.csv")

def try_detect(cell):
    try:
        detected_lang = detect(cell)
    except:
        detected_lang = None
    return detected_lang

# this took 13 mins to run on my machine
df['lang'] = df.txt.apply(try_detect)
df['lang'].value_counts(dropna=False)

en       54641
es        5857
NaN       5665
pt        5279
de        4218
zh-cn     2971
fr        2730
it        2286
ko        2010
ja        1324
ca        1280
nl        1065
da         968
id         811
ro         775
no         608
vi         546
tr         511
af         497
pl         487
cy         451
tl         445
sv         434
fa         417
et         369
he         348
fi         343
so         289
ru         270
sl         224
hr         210
cs         204
hu         203
ar         190
lt         182
sw         181
sk         160
lv         153
el         143
sq         104
zh-tw       37
th          35
bg          26
uk          21
mk          15
ur          13
ta           1
ml           1
bn           1
hi           1
Name: lang, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey, looks good but how do i do this if the dataframe is via a csv file?

Comment: You just need to read the csv into a dataframe. I added the line to do that in the answer.

Comment: But now the line ['something in english] etc is overwriting the csv df?

Comment: Yes, I was only trying to give you a complete example so that you can see the result. This is important: you should always provide a reproducible example with data so that people don't have to come up with their own data in order to provide a solution). You just need to delete the row in which I created the dataframe and use the df that results from the `read_csv` operation.

Comment: Ah ok, im getting the error 'expected string or bytes-like object' when running this with my csv file now, seems to be the issue i ran into before, any idea?

Comment: Where does the error happen? Are you able to load the csv into a dataframe? If so, can you provide an example (just a few rows) of your data?

Comment: ive updated the main post, error happens on 'df.apply(lambda x: detect(x))'

Comment: Notice that in my solution I use `apply` on the `txt` variable, not on the dataframe. Notice that doing it like this you don't need to delete the other variables before you use `apply`.

Comment: yes, merely dropped the others and removed the txt to see whether it would resolve it, same error either way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168501/discussion-between-box-and-oriol-mirosa).